three.js set break when using Line2 and LineMaterial
I have a bunch of points that are part of each cube face and are set in consecutive order.
when passing all those points to the LineGeometry there is a diagonal line as a result of connecting all the data points. Is there a way of jumping onto a new point?
What I tried is to set vertex colors, however, it creates a weird effect and I also can not set a transparent color.
const pos =
  edgeLines.geometry.clone().attributes.position;
const geoLine = new LineGeometry();
const linePositions: number[] = [];
const lineColors: number[] = [];

for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
  const s = k * 6;
  const val1 = (pos.array as Float32Array).slice(
    s,
    s + 3
  );
  const v1 = mesh.localToWorld(
    new THREE.Vector3(val1[0], val1[1], val1[2])
  );
  const val2 = (pos.array as Float32Array).slice(
    s + 3,
    s + 6
  );
  const v2 = mesh.localToWorld(
    new THREE.Vector3(val2[0], val2[1], val2[2])
  );
  linePositions.push(
    v1.x,
    v1.y,
    v1.z,
    v2.x,
    v2.y,
    v2.z
  );
  lineColors.push(k % 2 === 0 ? 1 : 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  //add an extra line to close the shape!
  if (k !== 0 && (k + 1) % 2 === 0) {
    const kk = k - 1;
    const ss = kk * 6;
    const _val1 = (pos.array as Float32Array).slice(
      ss,
      ss + 3
    );

    const _v1 = mesh.localToWorld(
      new THREE.Vector3(_val1[0], _val1[1], _val1[2])
    );
    linePositions.push(_v1.x, _v1.y, _v1.z);
    lineColors.push(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
geoLine.setPositions(linePositions);
geoLine.setColors(lineColors);
const matLine = new LineMaterial({
  // color: "red",
  linewidth: 2,
  resolution: gl.getSize(new THREE.Vector2()),
  alphaToCoverage: true,
  vertexColors: true,
});
const line = new Line2(geoLine, matLine);
line.computeLineDistances();
line.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add(line);


